# Android Viewmodel savestate using dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am using ViewModel savestate handle in my app, I inject ViewModel using the dagger, So I used AssistInject to inject `SaveStateHandle` in to viewmodel. Everything works fine for me, But one thing I need to know is that I need to pass the bundle which I received in the fragment to the savestatehandle. So in my fragment module, I provide the method injection for the fragment/activity which am using and get the arguments/intent and so while using the scope I can get the same bundle in the viewmodel factory.

Example:
Dagger Fragment/Activity module class

```
@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [TestingModule::class])
abstract fun bindTestingScreenFragment(): TestingScreen
```

**TestingModule::class**

```
@Module(includes = [TestingModule.TestingAbstractModule::class])
class TestingModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDefaultArgs(testingScreen: TestingScreen): Bundle? = testingScreen.arguments

    @Module
    abstract class TestingAbstractModule {
        @Binds
        abstract fun bindTestingScreen(testingScreen: TestingScreen): SavedStateRegistryOwner
    }
}
```

The doubt which i had is in the `provideDefaultArgs` method i inject the screen which i am currently injecting for, So how this works without the circular dependency error.                                                                                     does anyone have any idea on this ?